# Positioning the image buttons on multiple resolutions, Android

Tags: android

I have some Image Button on AbsoluteLayout, because they need to be placed on some parts on the ImageView.

I want that when I change the screen size resolution, the Image Buttons will stay at the exactly location on the ImageView.

The problem is that if I change the resolution, all the Image Buttons are moving from their places.

Maybe there is a way to place the Image Button without AbsoluteLayout on base of
ratio or percentage from the ImageView, because I know that AbsoluteLayout is not recommanded at all.

Thank you for the help

This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".G" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ScrollView1"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="100" >

            <AbsoluteLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_weight="20"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ScrollView1" >
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/tvOn"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/t" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="319dp"
                    android:layout_y="88dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_blue" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_x="287dp"
                    android:layout_y="125dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/b_blue" />

            </AbsoluteLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvOn"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_weight="80" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="85"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/rGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/bmD"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/bmCt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First, I suggest to use RelativeLayout instead of AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Ok, so how can I place the Button randomly on the screen and save the position after changing the resolution like I mentioned before?

Comment: Hmmmm... I would use a different approach in this case. I think using only XML to ensure the button position is not a good idea. I would use some code to get the exac position for the "sensible" areas of the image.

Comment: Can you give me example of this code?